# Как прибавить число к последнему числу в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть какое то определенное значение, получаю последнее в нем число, если оно есть прибавляю к нему 1.

Подскажите как связать с ним все то что идет до этого числа ?

```
// Возможные значения => результат:
// test => test-2
// test-0 => test-1
// test-5847 => test-5848
// 3-4_6-doom-2-test-0 => 3-4_6-doom-2-test-1
// s3-4c6-doom-2-test-0890 => s3-4c6-doom-2-test-0891
// s3--2-test-08w90 => s3--2-test-08w90-2
// test527 => test527-2

$name = "test-458";
preg_match('/-[0-9]+$/', $name, $result);

if(isset($result[0])) $num = str_ireplace('-', '', $result[0]) + 1; else $num = 2;

echo $num; // 459
```

Как вывести `test-459` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$name="test";
preg_match('/-[0-9]+$/', $name, $var);
if(isset($var[0]))
echo preg_replace('/-[0-9]+$/', $var[0]-1, $name); 
else 
echo $name.='-2';
```

Comment: Такое значение не проходит `test527 => test527-2`, вернул `test528`

Comment: Не заметил, сейчас поправлю

Comment: спасибо, проходят все значения, кроме только этого `s3-4c6-doom-2-test-0890`, но это я уже знаю как поправить

Answer (score 0):

Для подобных целей имеется [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Получится нечто вроде

```
$name = "test-458";
$name = preg_replace_callback('/-(\d+)$/', function($matches){
               return $matches[1] + 1;
          }, $name);

print_r($name);
```

Comment: Вернул `test459`

Comment: @Spartacus вы тире не можете в код добавить или что?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'test-458';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~(?<=-)\d+$~',
    function($a){ return ++$a[0]; },
    $str
);
```

Результат:

```
test-459
```